# I want the color of the ball to change the red when it hits the wall.How do I add that code?

Tags: javascript, html

My Problem uploaded in codepen
`Click To see`
[Click to see](https://codepen.io/reza2811/pen/XWBJzYx)

`Click To Preview`
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJbBo.png)

Comment: We need to see your code here in the question. The task is quite simple, though. Create a variable named `color` having "yellow" as an initial value. In the collision detection part, when a collision is detected, change `color` to "red". Additionally, move the drawing part after the collision detection, and use `color` variable instead of the hard-coded value for `contex.fillStyle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look here. You have to add contex.fillStyle = "here put color you want"; into the if sections ;D You can look at this on my pen https://codepen.io/dzm11/pen/PoBwOrp

```
    window.onload = function () {
  //کنواهای بدنه را دریافت میکند
  var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
  var contex = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //ساخت چند متغیر-این برای پوزیشن ایکس و وای است
  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;
  //ساخت بیشتر از 2 متغیر-برای سرعته-اگر میخواهید حرکت را سریع ببینید-مقادیر را افزایش میدهد
  var dx = 2;
  var dy = -2;

  draw();

  function draw() {
    //تازه سازی کنواها
    contex.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    contex.beginPath();
    //اینجا با استفاده از آرک توپ زرد خودمان را ایجاد میکنیم
    contex.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    // contex.fillStyle="yellow";
    contex.fill();

    //دیوار
    if (x + dx > 480) {
      dx = -dx;
      contex.fillStyle = "red";
    }
    if (x + dx < 0) {
      dx = -dx;
      contex.fillStyle = "yellow";
    }
    if (y + dy > 320) {
      dy = -dy;
      contex.fillStyle = "blue";
    }
    if (y + dy < 0) {
      dy = -dy;
      contex.fillStyle = "black";
    }
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
  }
  setInterval(draw, 10);
};
```